# vba CreateObject("DataLink") specify 32 or 64 bit

Tags: vba, createobject

I am using the following to create a DataLink object and prompt user to create a DB connection:

```
Set oDLink = CreateObject("DataLinks")
sconnectionstring = oDLink.PromptNew()
```

The problem I have is that on a 64 bit machine it seams the 32 bit drivers are not listed.

So how can I specify that the 32 bit version of the DataLinks (dll) is used.
Presumably I want the one that is in the sysWOW64 folder.

I have seen that you can specify a ProgID using CreateObject, perhaps there is a different ProgID for the 32 bit & 64 bit versions, but I don't know what they might be.

Appreciate any help, spending so much time Googling without getting anywhere.

Comment: Snippet that gives a clue but not the answer from VBA:
(http://communities.bentley.com/other/old_site_member_blogs/bentley_employees/b/allen_brown_bentleys_blog/archive/2009/03/04/32-bit-database-connectivity-on-a-64-bit-os.aspx)

Comment: [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/06/29/650913.aspx) may help to determine many of the available ProgIDs on your system. It only returned one version of Datalinks on my 64-bit system though